# Android How to restrict user from copying data from Application Folder..?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and in my Project I got the requirement that the user should not be given a chance to copy images and videos in the application folder to the PC so that they cannot be reproduced.

Only the App should have the chance to access the images and videos stored in the App folder.

Comment: for application forlder you mean something stored into the SD Card?

Comment: Yes data stored in Application folder in SD Card

Comment: you can not. The only option is using encryption IMO

Comment: This is just a hunch but I don't think there's any way that can't be stepped around. It's the same problem with fighting software piracy. You could encrypt the images and videos, but that's just challenge for somebody determined.

Comment: and it will consume much resources and time for encrypting the Videos through mobile application which puts lot of burden on device.

Answer (score 1):

You can use internal storage and make your data private. For SD card use, i think its not possible, the documentation is clear: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Context.getDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) in private mode but keep in mind that this will be stored in the internal memory of the phone (Which could be limited in space).